# Unity rect is not showing up

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to create a health bar left up in the screen. I used this code but it doesn't show up in screen.

```
GUI.Box(new Rect(10, 10, Screen.width / 2 / (maxHealth / curHealth), 20), curHealth + "/" + maxHealth);
```

Probaly it's out of the screen. Even when the y cordinate is -10, it's still not showing up. I gave the script a gameobject, so it's not because of that. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Don't use `OnGUI` or `GUI.Box`. Use the new Unity UI System for this. See the duplicated question for more info.

Comment: My mistake was coding `OnGui` instead of `OnGUI`.

Comment: Still. Don't use that. If you are new to Unity, see the Unity UI [tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui)